# HMENU wrap only elements with children

Tags: typo3, typoscript

```
lib.menu.main  = HMENU
lib.menu.main {
  special = list
  special.value =  22,5,88,40,91
  alwaysActivePIDlist = 22,91
  1 = TMENU
  1.NO = 1        
  1.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  1.NO.wrapItemAndSub= <li class="sub-link">|</li>
  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul id="sub-menu">|</ul>
  2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
}   
MAIN_MENU < .lib.menu.main
```

I need to wrap first level `li`, if it has child elements, else nothing.
This code wraps all first level `li`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [**IFSUB**](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/CommonItemStates/Index.html) menu state - that's right what you need.

So, your code may look so:

```
lib.menu.main  = HMENU
lib.menu.main {
  ...
  1 = TMENU
  1.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  1.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  1.IFSUB = 1
  1.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="sub-link">|</li>
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's work. 
right code :
    1.IFSUB=1
    1.IFSUB{
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="sub-link">|</li>
    }